# Widget's Content Mssing in Child Theme

Tags: widgets, child-theme

After creating Child Theme with just style.css and functions.php, my content in widgets won't show up in child theme.

To clarify what I mean under 'Content in Widgets', lets take for example Footer Area Widget: If I write some text or HTML in widget, it won't show up in child theme.

Also, for some other widgets it puts content randomly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually all it did was:

Moved its content to widget below so I needed to move back every each of them to the original position. If anybody has proper description why is that happening I'd like to know.

Thanks